# Cannot unwrap parts of mesh?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm not able to unwrap the top and the bottom of the model to put texture for some reason.

[image: UV unwrap]

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Could you list the steps you are taking and explain what happens vs what you expect?

Comment: yes your question is not clear enough, it looks like you can unwrap as shown on your UV/Image Editor window

Comment: The only thing I know is that the top and bottom had no polygons then I selected the edges and press space to searched the fill option. After that, I selected some edges and turn them red to help the unwrapping process. After that I've selected everything and pressed U and the option to unwrap. With all that, I just get the sides textured. (Sorry if there's grammar errors. English is not my first language.)

Answer (score 1):

I just had to not use the fill option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm newbie with unwrapping models, but everything worked out for me using U key in edit mode with all the faces of the object selected, and  using smart uv unwraping of blender, i works smooth , i hope this works for you